# Did RAF fighter pilots wear ties while flying in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, military, united-kingdom, uniform

Did RAF fighter pilots wear ties while flying in WW2?

[image]

It seems like that would be uncomfortable, if not dangerous, while you are experiencing high-Gs and low oxygen. However, the above movie includes Wellum himself (portrayed above), so presumably the producers had a chance to consult him.

Comment: Do you want to know if all RAF pilots wore ties or if any pilots wore ties or if regulations stated that they should (or should not) wear ties while flying?

Comment: @SteveBird Just the percentage of flight-hours attributed to tie-wearing pilots will do.

Comment: Seems like uniform regulations and images should be available online. What have you checked so far?

Comment: Not really proof of anything but the Wikipedia page for Wellum (who's the subject of the picture in the question) has [a picture of Wellum and his CO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Wellum#/media/File:Brian_Kingcome_IWM_HU_112488.jpg) in flying gear without their ties.

Comment: During the Battle of Britain, I imagine that the pilots flew wearing whatever they had on when the alarm sounded.

Comment: @KillingTime Like [here](https://263i3m2dw9nnf6zqv39ktpr1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Americans-battleCH_002401-800x450-1200x0-c-default.jpg)?

Comment: @MaxB I'm curious how you think anyone would determine "_the percentage of flight-hours attributed to tie-wearing pilots_"?  Do you think their attire was recorded in their flight logs?

Comment: @LаngLаngС: the chap to the right in that photo looks like he's wearing a tie...

Comment: It should be noted that in the UK in the 1940s ties were common in places that would seem unlikely today. The photographs of blue collar workers show them working with ties, what nowadays would seem uncomfortable and dangerous. In that context, flying with ties doesn't seem out of place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick browse through the imperial war museum collection suggests that ties were relatively common.

This picture shows two pilots with ties and one with some sort of scarf (which could be hiding a tie underneath)
https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205452816

https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205446953 shows a Canadian pilot with a tie.

Just for good measure this photo shows 3 polo necks and two ties
https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205209999

So in terms of the book picture I would say it's fine but I'm struggling to find proper combat pictures with ties visible there is a few "scramble" pictures for example
https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205447273 but I'm not sure how many were just for the camera.